# Access videos stored in red5 using actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, red5

i currently use the above code:

```
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);           
    ns = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.play("http://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/myvideo.flv");
    ns.client = nsClient;
    video = new Video();
    video.attachNetStream(ns);
    uic.addChild(video);
```

but i cant get the myvideo which i recorded using red5.how can i achieve that? myvideo is stored in red5 folder under webapps/oflaDemo/streams/myvideo how to access that in order to play it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it have to be something like this:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://localhost:5080/oflaDemo");           
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.play("myvideo.flv");
ns.client = nsClient;
video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream(ns);
uic.addChild(video);
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally just saved my video one step backwards in a folder called recordings and put only the line:

```
ns.play("http://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/recordings/firstattempt.flv");
```

in order to play the recorded video!